# Display only a single state with counties from a full US counties map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to display a single state from a full US counties map?

I know I can get each states shape file and counties and create the topojson, but I'd rather work with one file if thats possible.

For example take Mike Bostock's full US county map.
[US Counties Map](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4122298)
Would it be possible to show just NY from this?

I haven't seen any examples showing that type of functionality.

Comment: you would have to create a mask to filter out the rest of the map that wasn't in that state;  how would you do that without each state's shape file?

Comment: yup, you're right. I would need those files anyway. Thanks

Comment: you would not need shape file of other counties if you want to show just NY, on the contrary, you need shape file containing just NY. Or if you could get topojson containing county names you could filter the selection based on name.

Comment: @ChiragKothari thanks. so If I understand correctly..with the full us counties json I could mask with the NY shape file then display just NY...with the counties of course

Comment: @Claies  FYI I ended up creating a mask as you suggested along with some tinkering from a couple of other examples. Thanks again. https://bl.ocks.org/gregdevs/a73f8a16f129757c037e72ecdebdd8f2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working off of [project to bounding box](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858) and created a clipping path around the state I wanted to display.

[NY State W/ Counties - Clipped](https://bl.ocks.org/gregdevs/a73f8a16f129757c037e72ecdebdd8f2)

Answer (score 5):

Once you've established your d3.json wrapper, you can use JavaScript filter method, so if your data has a'state' field:

`d3.json(filename, function(error, data){ var single=data.filter(function(d){
return d.state==='Ohio';}
}`

And then use the new single variable as your data for d3

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something similar based off of a couple of examples. I return the id and set a clip path. Thanks. https://bl.ocks.org/gregdevs/a73f8a16f129757c037e72ecdebdd8f2

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very late answer. However, it might be helpful for other people in the future.

This is an example of how to extract one state from the USA map file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
        fill: lightgray;
        stroke: #000000;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        }


path:hover {
        fill:orange;
        cursor:pointer;
      }

#state-borders {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-width: 10.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}


</style>
<body> 
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    centered;

var projection =  d3.geoAlbersUsa()
    .scale(1370)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("us-counties-github.json",function(json){
  console.log(json);


    svg.selectAll("path")
       .attr("id", "state_fips")
       .data(topojson.feature(json, json.objects.collection).features.filter(function(d) { return d.properties.state_fips == 36; }))
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .attr("stroke","white")
       .attr("fill", "gray");



    });
</script>
```

*I downloaded the dataset from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/deldersveld/topojson/master/countries/united-states/us-albers-counties.json "the counties are included in this file".

Comment: If you want to have different state, u just need to change the state_fips number to whatever u want.